# Laravel: After I upload files into server special character showing (Black Question Mark)

Tags: php, html, laravel

I created laravel project a (FRENCH LANGUAGE) and I already done it, after i update my project and upload the new files in the server all special character become black question mark, I don't know why it happens.

I read some answer, that say I need to use the UTF-8 but in laravel the utf-8 is exist to the head tag. Thanks

**View Code**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Olympus Website</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('/public/favicon.ico') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('/public/css/custom.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('/public/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
        <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

        {{-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> --}}
    <body>


        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; z-index:999999999;">

            {{-- <div class="container"> --}}
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('index') }}">
                            <img src="{{asset('/public/Images/nav-logo.png')}}" height="30" alt="">
                        </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">


                    @if(Request::path() == 'index' || Request::path() == '/')
                       <li class="nav-item {{ Request::path() == 'index' ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="/index" class="nav-link"  style="color:#6534ff !important; font-weight:600;">Accueil</a></li>
                     @else
                        <li class="nav-item {{ Request::path() == 'index' ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="/index" class="nav-link">Accueil</a></li>
                     @endif


                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">


                        @if(Request::path() == 'story' || Request::path() == 'community' || Request::path() == 'peoplegallery')

                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color:#6534ff !important; font-weight:600;">
                            À Propos de nous 
                            </a>

                        @else
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            À Propos de nous 
                            </a>

                        @endif

                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('story') }}">Historique de la compagnie</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('community') }}">Communauté</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('peoplegallery') }}">Galerie de personnes</a>
                    </li>

                     @if(Request::path() == 'news_event')
                       <li class="nav-item"><a href="{{ url('news_event') }}" class="nav-link" style="color:#6534ff !important; font-weight:600;">Nouvelles et événements</a></li>
                     @else
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="{{ url('news_event') }}" class="nav-link">Nouvelles et événements</a></li>
                     @endif



                    @if(Request::path() == 'directory')
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('directory') }}" style="color:#6534ff !important; font-weight:600;">Répertoire de magasin</a>
                        </li>
                     @else
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('directory') }}">Répertoire de magasin</a>
                        </li>
                     @endif

                     @if(Request::path() == 'careers')
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('careers') }}" style="color:#6534ff !important; font-weight:600;">Carriéres</a>
                        </li>
                     @else
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('careers') }}">Carriéres</a>
                        </li>
                     @endif

                     @if(Request::path() == 'contact')
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('contact') }}" style="color:#6534ff !important; font-weight:600;">Contactez-nous</a>
                        </li>
                     @else
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('contact') }}">Contactez-nous</a>
                        </li>
                     @endif


                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        @guest
                             @if(Request::path() == 'login')
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('login') }}" style="color:#6534ff !important; font-weight:600;">Se connecter </a>
                                </li>
                             @else
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('login') }}">Se connecter </a>
                                </li>
                             @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('hiflyerdashboard') }}">Dashboard</a>

                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>



                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            {{-- </div> --}}
        </nav>

        @yield('content');


        <br><br><br><br>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer class="page-footer font-small blue" style="background-color:black; color:white; width:100%;">

          <!-- Copyright -->
          <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© <?php echo date("Y"); ?>
             Olympus Food .Conçu par des experts en solutions et des facilitateurs, Inc.
          </div>
          <!-- Copyright -->

        </footer>
        <!-- Footer -->

        <script src="{{asset('/public/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js')}}" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('/public/js/popper.min.js')}}" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('/public/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

        <script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Where does this text come from? Is it plain text in a view or does it come from a database/variable?

Comment: it just a plain text.

Comment: Please post the view code for this

Comment: @Jerodev ok thanks jerodev